# unable to pass vars with segue

Tags: objective-c, core-data, ios5, storyboard, segue

I'm doing some very simple Core Data stuff with a storyboard, I am able to pass vars with segue but for some reason this one won't let me.

I am trying to segue form this class to `BlogDetailsViewcontroller` with this call

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{    
    if (segue.identifier == @"User'sBlogList2BlogDetails")
    {
        NSLog(@"this is self.users.sorted %@", self.user.sortedBlogs);

        BlogDetailsViewController *bdvc = segue.destinationViewController;
        bdvc.blog = [self.user.sortedBlogs objectAtIndex:self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow.row];
        bdvc.temp = @" this is temp pass";      
    }
}
```

This is `BlogDetailsViewController` class

```
@class Blog;

@interface BlogDetailsViewController : UITableViewController
{
   NSString *temp;
}

@property(nonatomic, strong) Blog *blog;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *temp;

@end

@implementation

@synthesize blog, temp;

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSLog(@"%@,%@", blog, temp); //comes back as null for both !!
}
```

It worked fine for the other class, I did nothing different.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `==` means you are doing a pointer comparison on the segue identifier, what you need is

```
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"User'sBlogList2BlogDetails"]) {
```

Comment: Wow, spot on Paul!  I guess i saw it in the tut and didn't think twice about it.